# Adding Parameter to URL to Iterate in Python

Tags: python, api, post, parameters, iterator

I have a Python script that I'm working on where I would like to iterate through a list of ID values at the end of a URL.

This is my script so far where I would like to replace the 555 portion of the url with a list of ID values such that the script would do a POST for each of them. How can I accomplish that?

```
#/bin/python3
import requests

url = "https://api.bleepbloop.com/v8/account/555"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer 123456"}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: What values do you have in mind? Can you create a list of them? Can you iterate over that list and print them out one by one?

Comment: @quamrana - That is what I need help with. How do I create the list to iterate through them in the URL? I am not sure how to proceed with that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, with the `range` function to create a list of ids:

```py
#/bin/python3
import requests

base_url = "https://example.com/api/"
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer 123456"}
ids = [1,2,3,4] # or range(5)
for id in ids:
    response = requests.request("POST", base_url + str(id), headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
```

(working example: https://replit.com/@LukeStorry/67988932)

Comment: I get the following error with this:

response = requests.request("POST", f"{base_url}/{id}", headers=headers)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That's odd, works fine for me.
Could be an issue with the f-strings, try again with the updated question (I changed to `base_url + str(id)` instead of `f"{base_url}/{id}"`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This worked for me. In my research, it seems that I may have been getting errors with the f-string due to my environment using Python 2.7 so I will need to try a more recent version of Python and see if that works.